# Prolog - Why does my definition for append_list not return the combined list?

Tags: prolog

```
% appends an element to the beginning of a list. 

append_element(X, T, [X|T]).

% append a list to another list to create a combined list,
% by breaking the first list apart, and using append_element.

append_list([], L, L).

append_list([H|T], L, NewList) :- 
    append_element(H, L, NL), 
    append_list(T, NL, NL).
```

When I try to run append_list,

```
?- append_list([1,2], [3, 4, 5], NL).
```

I get back false. Instead of

```
NL = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5].
```

Why?

Comment: `append_list(T, NL, NL).` should be `append_list(T, NL, NewList).`

Comment: % **pre**pends an element (to the beginning of) a list.